# Proving that $I\cap J=(0)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $I,J$ be $R$-submodules where exists an idempotent element $e=e^{2}\in R$ such that $I=Re$ y $J=R(1-e)$.

I have read that under these circumstances it is fulfilled that $I\cap J=(0)$. How could I prove that?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary element $x\in I\cap J$. Then since $x\in Re$ and $e$ is idempotent, we have $xe = x$. Also, because $x\in R(1-e)$ and $1-e$ is idempotent, we have $x(1-e) = x$. Thus
$$
x = xe = x(1-e)e = x(e-e^2) = x(e-e) = 0
$$

Comment: but you shouldn't put $x = x'y$ and $x=x'(1-e)$ with $x\neq x'$?

Comment: @user725514 I did skip an intermediate step when I said that $x\in Re \implies xe = x$, yes (and similar for $1-e$). But that's not the correct intermediate step. No need for $x'\neq x$. And you need the $x'$ for $e$ and the $x'$ for $1-e$ to have different names (as we don't yet know that they are equal).

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance ... I understand what you mean, but I don't understand how to get from that to $x=xe$ and $x=x(1-e)$.

Comment: Because $x\in Re$, there is some $x'$ such that $x = x'e$. Then $xe = x'e^2 = x'e = x$ (no reason to assume $x\neq x'$; they may be, and indeed turn out to be, equal). A very similar argument applies to the $1-e$ case.

Comment: Oh, it´s true! Thank you so much!